# merging data frames confusion

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a bit confused with merging a couple of dataframes.  The following dataframes are called (dayData and data):

dayData:

```
               id          stock_name    broad_sector currency
0  BBG.XLON.BTA.S        BT GROUP PLC  Communications      GBp
1  BBG.XLON.VOD.S  VODAFONE GROUP PLC  Communications      GBp

dayData type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
dayData index  [0 1]
```

data:

```
            id
BBG.XLON.BTA.S    301.221525
BBG.XLON.VOD.S    213.791400

Name: 2008-02-20 00:00:00, dtype: float64
data index  [0 1]
```

the dayData dataframe is a Series so I convert to a dataframe and then try and merge the datae dataframes:

```
data = data.to_frame().reset_index()
data.columns = ['id', 'price']
dayData = dayData.merge(data[['price']], left_on='id', right_index=True)
```

however the returned dayData dataframe is empty:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [id, stock_name, broad_sector, currency, price]
Index: []
```

What I am hoping to return is:

```
               id          stock_name    broad_sector currency       price
0  BBG.XLON.BTA.S        BT GROUP PLC  Communications      GBp  301.221525
1  BBG.XLON.VOD.S  VODAFONE GROUP PLC  Communications      GBp  213.791400
```

Any idea what I've done wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: You reset the index but you then try to merge on the index here: `dayData = dayData.merge(data[['price']], left_on='id', right_index=True)` why not just use the common column names: `dayData = dayData.merge(data[['price']], on='id')`?

Comment: Given the well stripped down sample data soze, would it be possible to have running code snippet in the question? Lodaing data into frame, etc. It would help me a lot to contribute, otherwise, I tend to stare at the printouts, and click further ;-)

Comment: Thankd Ed, I tried implementing your change but the code returns: KeyError: 'id',  any idea how I set the id to the index?

Comment: sorry I just noticed you're trying to merge on a single column df try `dayData = dayData.merge(data, on='id')`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) `Serie` to `DataFrame`, but before set `Serie name` to `price` by `data.name = 'price'` :

```
print (dayData)

               id          stock_name    broad_sector currency
0  BBG.XLON.BTA.S        BT GROUP PLC  Communications      GBp
1  BBG.XLON.VOD.S  VODAFONE GROUP PLC  Communications      GBp

data.name = 'price'
print (data)

id
BBG.XLON.BTA.S    301.221525
BBG.XLON.VOD.S    213.791400
Name: price, dtype: float64

dayData = dayData.join(data, on='id')

print (dayData)
               id          stock_name    broad_sector currency       price
0  BBG.XLON.BTA.S        BT GROUP PLC  Communications      GBp  301.221525
1  BBG.XLON.VOD.S  VODAFONE GROUP PLC  Communications      GBp  213.791400
```

[Joining key columns on an index](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#joining-key-columns-on-an-index).